# Modelling an object travelling through an atmosphere

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling, projectile-motion

I am trying to model an object travelling through an atmosphere of uniform density with a uniform gravitational acceleration.

I have the two equations that will describe the forces, $F_g = mg$ and $F_d = kv^2$. Combining these together with $F = ma$ will yield $mg + kv^2 = ma$.

This equation has its issues, since the force of drag will always be positive, and it needs to be either positive or negative depending on which direction the object it travelling in. My only idea on how to fix this is by multiplying the drag force by a factor of $-\frac{v}{|v|}$, however this seems hacky and annoying to work with.

Are there any better ways of getting around this problem?

Comment: Which of the million websites that illustrate this problem did you find confusing?

Comment: would you kindly link one of those millions of websites, since i found none that solved my problem

Comment: The Google search "projectile with air resistance" returned 3,140,000 hits.

Comment: The best way to solve this is to define your coordinate axes carefully, and use the correct signs. For example: you have $mg$ in your equation. That's always pointed down. Are you defining $y$ positive up or down? You can do it either way, but once you do that, it forces the rest of your Newton's 2nd Law to look a certain way.